# How can I allow users to upload multiple images and files in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to create functionality like facebook/twitter for creating a post. I have a url smth like `example.com/username/posts/create` with the form related to the post model. As you probably know, there is no ability in vanilla ImageField & FileField to upload multiple items, as well as no decent editor for drag&drop like things. Drag&Drop isn't a crucial feature, but I really want to handle with a twitter/facebook like editor somehow. With all it's convenient buttons for photo/video/file.

I saw there is a bunch of custom editors like DJANGO-CKEDITOR and etc., but I don't understand how it suppose to work anyway with one image/file field. Maybe, somebody was facing the problem?

Attach my form and model in case it will help:

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="posts/images")
    body = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserPostRel', related_name='likes')
```

forms.py

```
class PostCreationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
            'body',
            'images',

        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].label = "Title"
        self.fields['body'].label = "Body"
        self.fields['images '].label = "images"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this is done through an extra model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='UserPostRel', related_name='likers'
    )


class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/images')
```

Then we make a small form to handle the bulk upload:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    files = forms.FileField(
        label='',
        required=False,
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
            'body',
        ]
        labels = {'title': 'Title', 'body': 'Body'}

    def _save_m2m(self):
        super()._save_m2m()
        images = [
            PostImage(post=self.instance, image=file)
            for file in self.files.get('files')
        ]
        PostImage.objects.bulk_create(images)
```

Then in the view we let the form handle this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render


def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'name-of-some-template.html', {'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Hello! Many thanks for this answer, it helps a lot with the understanding. Anyway, as far as I can see, there is need to update answer a little: In the view it actually need to call form.save_m2m(). And for some reason I get the "AttributeError: 'PostForm' object has no attribute 'object'" when trying to do that..

Comment: @jmur: sorry, I made a typo: it is `self.instance`, not `self.object`.